# How to find out whether the point belongs to the specified line?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, gis

I have a base lines (steps) of the route:
[image]

I have the coordinates of the point, which is exactly one of these routes. How do I know which section of a route is the point?

Answer (score 0):

This seems more of a math problem to which the solution is:

Go through the array of lines and test:

```
test_point=(x,y);
for each line (x1,y1),(x2,y2) in the array of lines{
   if(x1<x&x<x2&y1<y&y<y2)&&  
     ((x-x1)/(y-y2)~=(x-x2)/(y-y2))) the point lies in the given line
}
```

basically, make sure the point x1<=x<=x2&y1<=y<=y2 and the slope of (x1,y1) to (x,y) and (x,y) to (x2,y2) are approximately equal.